# Access Dynamics CRM with certificate

Tags: wcf, iis, dynamics-crm, client-certificates, dynamics-crm-2015

We got a Dynamics CRM (and Sharepoint) standard on-premise installation (not an Internet Facing Deployment for various reasons). The installation is still accessible from the internet.

We are AD-integrated. Still, users can access the data with username/password only. since all users and clients/devices are known I would like to introduce an additional layer of security by adding certificates (only machines with certificate installed may access the server/service).

Question: How do I do that?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't

Comment: I had the silent hope that this could be achieved with standard IIS methods like "Require client certificate". Any known limitations regarding this with Dynamics CRM or Sharepoint?

Comment: I don't recall any dynamics-specific indications about this kind of configuration on MSDN